Product of Irreducible Matrices
In tropical algebra, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$ and
$$a\oplus b:=\max\{a,b\},\quad a\otimes b:=a+b$$
for all $a,b\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. This notion is extended to matrices in a natural way. For $A,B$ matrices over $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ of appropriate sizes $A\oplus B$ is defined component wise and for $A\otimes B$ we have
$$(A\otimes B)_{ij}:=\bigoplus_{k=1}^na_{ik}\otimes b_{kj}$$
With this in mind, a matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}^{n\times n}$ is called irreducible if for all $i,j\in[n]$, with $i\ne j$, there exists a sequence of indices $i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_k\in[n]$ without repetition such that $i_0=i$, $i_k=j$ and $a_{i_ti_{t+1}}\ne-\infty$ for all $t\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$
Is it true that the product of two irreducible matrices is irreducible? this seems to be true but I've been having a bit of trouble trying to prove it my self. I've not been able to find the proper references for this either. Any hint would be useful.
The notion of irreducibility is also equivalent to saying that the graphs are strongly connected, which is also useful for my purposes.
Thanks
